# What expression would I use?

Tags: javascript, php, passwords

What regular expression would I use for checking if a string contains at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, a symbol, and a number? I am using PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: Can we assume that by expression you mean "regular expression" ? Maybe knowing the exact term was what prevented you from searching a little ?

Comment: I already searched all over the place. @dystroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).+$/', $string);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(preg_match("/^.(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST["string"])
```

i hope this works

Comment: That did not seem to work for me.

Comment: can you specify what kind of symbols you need